# Retrieve Siebel data based on intersection table using SiebelDataBean

Tags: java, siebel

I have Siebel structure looking like this:

BusObj: Base
--BusComp: Category list
----BusComp: Product list

"Product list" is child component to "Category list", they have a link Category list/Product list by the means of intersection table 'S_CAT_PROD', that has CAT_ID for category and PROD_ID for product. This allows N-to-N linking of categories to products.

Now the problem is I have retrieved both SiebelBusComp from Java code, but have no idea how to make use of this intersection table to retrive all products for some category.

There are couple SiebelBusComp methods that return another SiebelBusComp, but I had no luck making them work. These are:

```
getAssocBusComp()
getMVGBusComp(java.lang.String fieldName)
getPicklistBusComp(java.lang.String fieldName)
parentBusComp()
```

Has anyone any experience using such logic in Java? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the table S_CAT_PROD in Siebel, assuming it is custom made. Again, assuming you have a M:M link from Catalog to Products correctly configured using this intersection table , the link itself will take care of filtering the child records based on parent category.

```
//make variable instances
var BO = TheApplication().GetBusObject("Base");
var bcCat = BO.GetBusComp("Category list");
var bcProd = BO.GetBusComp("Product  list");

//search for category

bcCat.ClearToQuery();
bcCat.SetSearchSpec("Id", "1-234");
bcCat.ExecuteQuery(True);

// When using the ExecuteQuery method with Java Data Bean, use True for //ForwardOnly and False for ForwardBackward.

if (bcCat.FirstRecord())
{
//the link will automatically filter and bring only those products for this //category

    bcProd.ClearToQuery();
    bcProd.ExecuteQuery(True);
}
```

Comment: This actually works, giant thanks to you, I've been struggling with this for at least a weak.